# shell script, loop array, why use ${array[@]}

Tags: shell

what is the "@" meaning,
code:

```
#!/bin/bash

array[0]=1
array[1]=2
array[2]=3
array[3]=4
array[4]=5

#work
for num in ${array[@]}
do
    echo $num
done

#not work
for num in array
do
    echo $num
done
```

In the loop, why use ${array[@]} not $array, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax defined by the language. This is just how it works. Read about it in `man bash`, search for the section titled "Arrays". Here's the relevant part:

> Any  element  of  an  array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.
>          The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion.  If
>          subscript  is  @  or * , the word expands to all members of name.  These
>          subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes.   If
>          the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the
>          value of each array member separated by the first character of the  IFS
>          special variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a sep‐
>          arate word.  When there are no array  members,  ${name[@]}  expands  to
>          nothing.   If  the  double-quoted  expansion  occurs within a word, the
>          expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning  part  of
>          the  original  word,  and the expansion of the last parameter is joined
>          with the last part of the original word.   This  is  analogous  to  the
>          expansion  of  the  special  parameters * and @ (see Special Parameters
>          above).

Answer (score 0):

`$array` doesn't work like an array.  It more nearly acts like `${array[0]}`.

Answer (score 0):

`$array` evaluates to the first element in the array. You must use `${array[@]}` (or more properly, `"${array[@]}"`) to indicate each element of the array in turn, separated by the first character of `$IFS`.